# Update Manager stuck in loop with non-existing update

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

When I open Update Manager, I'm presented with empty list saying there is 2,9 MB of updates. For a fact, there is none, I ran `apt update/upgrade` few seconds ago. Whe I click install, it seems like it's doing something, then it says it's finsihed, and then again, blank list and 2,9 MB of updates.

I've found [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1766217), suggesting deleting `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`, but it didn't helped. Deleteing the whole `/var/lib/apt/` did, but after running `apt update`, the problem is back again.

It prevents me from upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10.

Comment: If the workaround of deleting `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` did not work, then you have a discovered a different bug. Congratulations! Consider simply running `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal instead of through Update Manager. If the bug continues after the release-upgrade, then please report it properly.

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that there are newer versions of packages but they cannot be installed because of a conflict with another package or a package marked as held back.

You can run this command to see if you have any manually held packages:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

If the list is empty then it's likely that a different package you have installed requires a version of a library or other dependency that keeps the upgrade from happening.

You can run the `aptitude` tool in the command line to see more information about why packages are not being upgraded and what options are available. This command is similar to `apt upgrade` but will likely show more information:

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

You can also run this command which will install the latest packages, although it may remove some packages to do so:

```
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```